# Error: string index out of range

Tags: python

I coded the python function given below:

```
def processstring(string):
    gtkname=""
    if string[0]=="/":
        i=1
        while(string[i]!="/"):
            if i==len(string):
                break
            gtkname=gtkname+string[i]
            i=i+1
        return gtkname
    return string
```

when I execute the code it gives me the following error:

```
while(string[i]!="/"):
IndexError: string index out of range.
```

I don't know why is it giving this error.

Comment: Are you trying to remove // comments starter from the start of the string?

Comment: What is the input you are passing to the function while running the program ?

Comment: Remove the `i=1` line; also, what problem are you trying to solve with this function?

Comment: Condition should be `i+1==len(string)`, not `i==len(string)`, because python indicies are zero-based

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition is causing the error: `while string[i] != "/":`

After you increment `i`, you check that condition *before* you check `if i == len(string):` to break the loop. Move that check to the end of the loop:

```
    while(string[i]!="/"):
        gtkname=gtkname+string[i]
        i=i+1
        if i==len(string):
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not manipulating the iteration on string characters in a proper way

```
def processstring(string):
    if string[0]=="/":
        return string[1:string.find("/",1)]
    return string
```

Python give us ways to not using direct iteration on index of a list